# Error after updating to meteor v1.11. Conflict: Constraint email@1.2.3 is not satisfied by email 2.0.0

Tags: email, meteor

I'm having a problem with Meteor, after upgrading to v1.11.

Apparently is a [known issue](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-11-released/53791/7). Do you have a workaround for this message?

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Errors prevented startup:                  
   
   While selecting package versions:
   error: Conflict: Constraint email@1.2.3 is not satisfied by email 2.0.0.
   Constraints on package "email":
   * email@~2.0.0 <- top level
   * email@1.2.3 <- vulcan:lib 1.16.0
   * email@2.0.0 <- accounts-password 1.6.2
   * email@1.2.3 <- vulcan:accounts 1.16.0 <- clearbase:admin 0.1.0
   
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I've tried updating the dependencies with `meteor update`, then manually using `packagecheck` but still same issue. Also tried the suggestions on the meteor release post.

Comment: how did you update? did you only update the release or also all packages?

Comment: By the release, then all packages but still same issue. I used packagecheck to even manually update everything.

Comment: Looks like there are a bunch of suggestions in the forum post you linked to. Which of those have you already tried? Please add them to your question.

Comment: See the release notes, release 1.11 has a breaking change for the email package you can try by using `email@2.0.0!` in `.meteor/packages` if that doesnt work you may end up aksing the package owners to update or fork the dependencies (as already mentioned in the forum)

Comment: I tried it and still got the error. It seems `!` is accepted from the v1.11.1. Then that specific error disappears.

Answer (score 1):

This error is solved updating to *meteor v1.11.1*
Plus you need to add `!` at the end of the dependency on `packages`

```
# .meteor/packages

email@~2.0.0!
```